# Python распарсить текст из textarea

Tags: python, парсер

Прошу помочь. В POST прилетает такая конструкция:

```
aaaaa   11111
fffff   22222
```

Несколько строк. ключ/значение разделены табом и каждая пара с новой строки. Необходимо распарсить в словарь что бы получилось: {"aaaaa": "11111", "fffff": "22222"}
Может кто подскажет, как распарсить. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

я бы сделал так:

```
d = dict(x.split() for x in text.splitlines())
```

результат:

```
{'aaaaa': '11111', 'fffff': '22222'}
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает.

Answer (score 2):

?

```
= {line.split()[0]: line.split()[1] for line in text.split('\n')}
```

Comment: Спасибо ваш код тоже работает.